# Is it possible to have multicolored headings in markdown syntax in at least one of these editors: Sublime Text 3, Vim or Visual Studio Code?

Tags: vim, visual-studio-code, themes, sublimetext3, markdown

Essentially I would like for my headings to look like this:

[image: md]

How could I accomplish this in markdown syntax? I prefer sublime text but would be happy if I can make this happen in Sublime Text 3, Vim or Visual Studio Code. Lastly, if getting the subheadings to produce multicolors is difficult, then, how could I change the hashtag color of all headings to the same color. For example, all of my headings would have green hashtags but the heading font color would be `#FFFFFF`.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I found in vim that I can change the color of each markdown heading (markdownH1, markdownH2, etc) but this isn't what I am looking for --- I would like to change the color of the hashtag (#) for each heading/subheading or if not possible, just the hashtag color.

Comment: For VSCode, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66781629/3329384).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Vim, you can override your color scheme by adding the following in a new file named `~/.vim/after/syntax/markdown.vim`:

```
syn match    customHeader1     "^# "
syn match    customHeader2     "^## "
syn match    customHeader3     "^### "
syn match    customHeader4     "^#### "
syn match    customHeader5     "^##### "

highlight customHeader1 ctermfg=34
highlight customHeader2 ctermfg=32
highlight customHeader3 ctermfg=127
highlight customHeader4 ctermfg=45
highlight customHeader5 ctermfg=220
```

It creates 5 syntax groups (`customHeader1` to `customHeader4`) matching the given regexes. Then it defines the colors for those groups.

34, 32, 127, 45, 220 are the colors, They should match your example. It renders as follow:

[image: Result]

Also, you need to have:

```
syntax on
```

in your `.vimrc`

Comment: The default syntax for `Markdown` in Sublime only differentiates between level 1 and level 2 headers (everything else is just a generic heading). So while possible I think this would need syntax tweaks as well.

Answer (score 0):

With Sublime Text 3, you can also define one specific color for 3 header levels.

If you have already a theme with specific markdown colors, edit your .tmTheme file and search for

`<string>markup.heading, markup.heading punctuation</string>`

This is the default heading color that is used for all heading levels.

If you duplicate the parent <dict> block for this entry, you can put a specific color for 1st heading level (# in markdown) by changing <string> like this :

`<string>markup.heading.1, markup.heading.1 punctuation</string>`

if you duplicate one more you can change the 2nd level color (## in markdown) :

`<string>markup.heading.2, markup.heading.2 punctuation</string>`

Other levels ### etc. are not defined so you cannot add specific colors for them (but it is in fact still possible if you modify your *Markdown.sublime-syntax* file and extends it to other heading levels, with the same type of patterns code used for level 1 and level 2 headings)

Answer (score 0):

I just checked by adjusting my settings and it is possible in the latest vscode

[image]

To get the above set the textMateRules to the following to your json settings

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
   "textMateRules": [
   ]
{
    "scope": "heading.1.markdown",
    "settings": {
      "fontStyle": "bold underline",
      "foreground": "#8596c5a9"
    }
  },
  {
    "scope": "heading.2.markdown",
    "settings": {
      "fontStyle": "bold",
      "foreground": "#9c7964" 
    }
  },
  {
    "scope": "heading.3.markdown",
    "settings": {
      "fontStyle": " italic",
      "foreground": "#cd2d87a9"
    }
  },
  {
    "scope": "heading.4.markdown",
    "settings": {
      "fontStyle": " italic",
      "foreground": "#b8b64d" 
    }
  },
  {
    "scope": "heading.5.markdown",
    "settings": {
      "fontStyle": " italic",
      "foreground": "#da2a2a" 
    }
  }
}
```