# How can I change color of operators (+ - * / < >) in colorscheme file of vim

Tags: c++, vim, color-scheme

I downloaded colorscheme file for vim, and I want to change it to be what I like. So I tried to change the color in the file.

Now I can't see new color of operators such as `+ - * / < >`. Which there's one that is "Operator" type, but it only changes the operator like `and`,`or`,etc.

I've already tried to search for it in google and stackoverflow, which there's one about changing it using terminal. But I want the one that can be changed within the colorscheme file.

I downloaded colorscheme and use vimrc to change the colorscheme.
I am using c++.

Comment: Ok, I use [this](https://github.com/crusoexia/vim-monokai).

Answer (score 1):

As per my answer for a similar markdown [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55559850/is-it-possible-to-have-multicolored-headings-in-markdown-syntax-in-at-least-one/55560276#55560276) I gave, you can create `~/.vim/after/syntax/cpp.vim` and add a group and set a color for it. It would be something along the lines of:

```
syn match    addOperator     " \+ "

highlight addOperator ctermfg=34
```