# How do I change markdown heading color by heading level in VS Code editor?

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, colors, markdown, heading

My question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55559850/is-it-possible-to-have-multicolored-headings-in-markdown-syntax-in-at-least-one?r=SearchResults&s=2|53.3810) but the answer given there is for Vim and I need one for VS Code. I'm a real newbie, and I tried to solve this myself, but these attempts failed me:

- [Markdown Preview GitHub Styling](https://github.com/mjbvz/vscode-github-markdown-preview-style.git) - Says it allows user-defined custom css, but it styles html preview, not the text in the editor
- [Markdown Theme Kit](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-themes/blob/master/markdown-editing/README.md) - Points to custom .css files, but the included ones don't tell me how to do it differently for different heading levels
- [Markdown Header Coloring](https://github.com/satokaz/vscode-markdown-header-coloring) - Claims to do exactly this, but when I try to put in user-defined css to give each heading level a different color, I still get color changes between headings of the same level, even after closing/restarting VS Code.

Help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 12):

There is a built-in way to style text, including Markdown headings, in the editor without an extension, using [VSCode's Colour Theme](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/color-theme#syntax-colors) settings:

Open your `settings.json` (`~/.config/Code/User/settings.json`) or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> "settings", and between the top-level `{}` insert [for example](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/88841#issuecomment-575745168):

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "textMateRules": [
      {
          "scope": "heading.1.markdown entity.name.section.markdown, heading.1.markdown punctuation.definition.heading.markdown",
          "settings": {
              "foreground": "#9cecfb",
              "fontStyle": "bold",
          }
      },
      {
          "scope": "heading.2.markdown entity.name.section.markdown, heading.2.markdown punctuation.definition.heading.markdown",
          "settings": {
              "foreground": "#83a4d4",
          }
       }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Nice -- you may want to limit this color to a partular theme also, as in the "Semantic colors" example at the first link in this answer.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! I like these colors: https://www.colourlovers.com/palette/56122/Sweet_Lolly

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue and find a way with the VSCode extension ["Markdown header coloring"](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=satokaz.vscode-markdown-header-coloring)

Basically you have to

- install the extension
- set some custom settings in settings.json. You can find examples of custom settings in the section "User defined header coloring"
- **do not forget** to reload the window after each modification: open `Command Palette` → type `Reload window`
  Cheers