Different text color for headings in VS Code
When writing markdown files I would like to have different colors for different headings.

Is there a way in which I can match the # string in the beginning and change the color of that line accordingly in the user defined settings?

LMK if you want more details. I drafted an answer before I found that question, it just had some rough edges.

I think I'd need more help. I tried the solution in the link but I'm not sure how to differentiate between level 1 and level 2 headings.

Did you use the scope inspector? You should see heading.2.markdown vs heading.1.markdown. Or at least, that's what I see on mine.

This looks like the duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66781629/836330
